# How can I acces .py files that I have previously saved in IDLE and/or Jupyter?

Tags: python, python-idle, jupyter

I am pretty new to Python and I am struggling to access previously created classes/modules, and to access libraries/packages (like Scipy, pandas and matplotlib) I downloaded in IDLE and in Jupyter notebooks. I work with Python 3.4 under windows.

When I use a statement like

```
from ClassName import ClassName
```

in order to access previously saved .py files where these classes have been defined, I get the following error message:

ImportError: No module named 'ClassName'

If I am not mistaking, this most likely means that Python's interpreter is not 'looking in the right places' when I give these import statements, or when I want to use .py files. However, I have not (yet) been able to change/add PATHS

So my question is:

How do I ensure that I can access previously saved .py files in IDLE?
And how can I access these .py files in Jupyter?

Thanks in advance!

KR

Comment: Just use `import pandas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a notebook type:

```
ls
```

This shows all files in the current directory. If a file named `my_file.py` is displayed, you can import it:

```
import my_file
```

and can use it:

```
my_file.ClassName
```

Typically, the current working directory is on Python's search path for modules (`*.py` files). Therefore, using the command `cd <path/with/my/module>` in a notebook will bring you to the path in which your module is located. Now, you can import your module.

You can check where Python is searching for modules:

```
import sys

print(sys.path)
```

should show a list of paths names:

```
['',
 'a/path/to/somewhere',
 ....
]
```

The `''` stands for the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

In the IDLE click `File`, `Open` then locate the directory where your `.py` files are, find the file and open it.

Similarly, in Jupyter click the `File` tag then you will see a list of all the folders in your computer. Locate the folder then open the `.py` file.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem. When I try to use a class previously saved in a .py file, (via 'from ClassName import ClassName'), I keep getting the same error (ImportError: No module named 'ClassName'). How can I use the classes saved in a .py file in IDLE/Jupyter?

Comment: In your original question this is what you asked: "How do I ensure that I can access previously saved .py files in IDLE?" I answered this question. Now, in your comment you  said: "How can I use the classes saved in a .py file in IDLE/Jupyter?" That's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer for IDLE.  First, one does not typically download 3rd party packages *in IDLE*.  (There is a proposal to change this, but someone must write some code.)  Instead, one does downloads at a command line with pip (python install program).  By default, pip will put packages in site-packages directory, which is on the search path.  3.4 on Windows had pip installed.  For using pip, see the docs and questions here on SO.

For your own code, make a directory, such as 'mypy', in a directory you can write to, such as your home directory /users/theo (or whatever your login name it).  Edit a new file, and write something like

```
print('myclass imported')
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self): print('MyClass instance')
```

Save-as 'myclass' in the mypy directory.  Now open another new file and write

```
import myclass
mc = myclass.MyClass()
```

Save that with any name ('mycode'?) also in mypy.  Then hit F5 to run it and you should see two lines printed.